# How to use 'RAD Studio Command Prompt' with environment variables?

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe7

My project uses an environment variables in the output paths, i.e `$(MY_PROJECTS)\MyPackage` (in `Project -> Options -> Delphi Compiler -> Package output directory`)

The `MY_PROJECTS` environment variable is defined as `W:\Test` (in `Tools -> Options -> Environment Options -> Environment Variables -> User overrides`)

When I build or compile the project from the IDE, the output files are created in `W:\Test\MyPackage`.

If I build the project from the [*RAD Studio Command Prompt*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Building_a_Project_Using_an_MSBuild_Command), the output files are created in `W:\MyPackage` (as if it doesn't see the `MY_PROJECTS` environment variable).

```
cd W:\Source\MyPackage
msbuild MyPackage.dproj /t:build
```

How can I make sure it sees my environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've examined the *RAD Studio Command Prompt* and found that it's a link with the following destination:

```
%comspec%  /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
```

`rsvars` is a batch file who sets the default environment variables:

```
@SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0
@SET BDSINCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\include
@SET BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
@SET FrameworkVersion=v3.5
@SET FrameworkSDKDir=
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%FrameworkSDKDir%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin64;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBaseXE3\IDE_spoof;%PATH%
@SET LANGDIR=EN
@SET PLATFORM=
@SET PlatformSDK=
@SET CG_BOOST_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\include\boost_1_39
@SET CG_64_BOOST_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\include\boost_1_50
```

So the problem can be solved by following these steps:

1. Create an empty folder
2. Create a batch file named `setup_environment_variables.bat`

   ```
   REM ==== default environment variables ====
   CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\bin\rsvars.bat"

   REM ==== custom environment variables ====
   @SET MY_PROJECTS=W:\Test
   ```
3. Create a link named *Custom RAD Studio Command Prompt* with the following destination

   ```
   "%comspec% " /K ".\setup_environment_variables.bat"
   ```
4. Run *Custom RAD Studio Command Prompt* and it will see the `MY_PROJECT` environment variable and will create the output files in the expected directory.